# Expression Engine Contact Form

Tags: php, email, expressionengine

I am trying to create a custom contact form in Expression Engine but when I use EE's built in contact form tags:

`{exp:email:contact_form user_recipients="no" recipients="admin@example.com" charset="utf-8"}` and `{/exp:email:contact_form}`

The tags don't create the form open and close tags, it displays the text as if they weren't being read by EE.

I don't know if I am placing these in the wrong spot or what, but how can I get EE to recognize these tags and use them how they are supposed to be used? I tried adding them to the contact page through the EE admin panel. Am I supposed to do this through a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the E-mail module enabled in your CP? You can find and install it through your CP > Add-ons > Modules. It needs to be enabled / installed for the tags to work.